# Upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 GRUB menu hidden

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, 20.04

I'm quite new to Ubuntu world and installed Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot with Windows 10); all good, no problems, all works.

When upgraded to 20.04, i don't see the GRUB menu, just 10 seconds of nothing, then Ubuntu 20.04 starts (with no other problem). I can't choose what to start, which is really annoying.

I tried fixing GRUB with the installation LiveUSB, but could not.
I edited /etc/default/grub at the line by changing
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden" to add "menu" but that didn't work.

I tried ESC during the 10 second blackout, and get the menu but nothing.

I then erased all of Ubuntu 20.04 and reinstalled 20.04 from the beginning, only to still get the same problem.

Then tryed the uBuntu 19.10 and again same problem.

So I got back to the 20.04 because i want really get it to work properly.

Does anyone knows how to fix it? Why i can't get what to run with the 20.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: i all ready try to repair the GRUB from live usb no working, the problem is not Windows is the GRUB from 20.04 because doesn't show up i see black screen for 10sec then in to ubuntu to get to Windows i need access the boot load. As i write on the Question.

Comment: I'm not suggesting the problem is with Windows, simply suggesting that the boot loader needs to be reinstalled. Which of the 24 answers to the suggested duplicate question did you try? What exactly were the results? "no working" isn't very useful from a troubleshooting standpoint. Please [edit] your question to include exactly what you tried and what the results were. Include any error messages that you encountered and where you encountered them. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub menu working but hidden, can't make it visible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142167/grub-menu-working-but-hidden-cant-make-it-visible)

Answer (score 6):

Same problem though I installed Ubuntu 20.04 instead of upgrading.

A way for that:
edit `/etc/default/grub` to change `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` and remove `#` in front of `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`. Finally, run `sudo update-grub` in terminal

Comment: It worked now i can see again the GRUB menu do you may know how to get the Theme working? i try from GRUB Customizer, but nothing just ordinary GRUB.

Comment: I also want to know. I have tried what i could find by google, but none worked. May be grub2.04 have a issue on graphical mode.

Comment: `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` was what helped my install. I had `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` but Ubuntu (or MATE desktop) graphical boot menu was hiding the grub menu. As always, don't forget `sudo update-grub`. Ubuntu 20.04.2 with MATE desktop

Answer (score 0):

Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while it's booting up.