# grub doesn't show up in a dual boot system after partially upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, partial-upgrade

[Boot Repair log](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YMVHDf8WXh/)

I have a dual boot system which has Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 which is partially upgraded to 20.04, but during the partial upgrade I selected something without reading which made grub not show up during the boot. Both OSs are working, but I have to use the system keys like F12 to boot the other operating system.

grub2 was installed in sda2 system partition of Windows 10 in the efi directory.

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

/usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd_terminal.sh: line 177: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sdb1,
using the following options:        sda2/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups


/boot/efi added in sdb1/fstab
rm /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount sda2 on /boot/efi

================= Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of sdb1 ==================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.4

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0006,0002,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,6ad7128b-922e-4ee4-9baa-0ffaa5c0a297,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,GPT,78d781ef-526f-4d41-ad45-e941faf2f2be,0x276800,0x1f4000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootLrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0006* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,6ad7128b-922e-4ee4-9baa-0ffaa5c0a297,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

uname -r
5.4.0-51-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: Cannot set EFI variable Boot0000.
grub-install: warning: efivarfs_set_variable: writing to fd 7 failed: Invalid argument.
grub-install: warning: _efi_set_variable_mode: ops->set_variable() failed: Invalid argument.
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Invalid argument.
Exit code: 1
df /dev/sda2
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: Cannot set EFI variable Boot0000.
grub-install: warning: efivarfs_set_variable: writing to fd 7 failed: Invalid argument.
grub-install: warning: _efi_set_variable_mode: ops->set_variable() failed: Invalid argument.
grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Invalid argument.
Exit code: 1

---- Grub-install recheck

/usr/sbin/grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot --recheck
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
/usr/sbin/grub-install: warning: Cannot set EFI variable Boot0000.
/usr/sbin/grub-install: warning: efivarfs_set_variable: writing to fd 7 failed: Invalid argument.
/usr/sbin/grub-install: warning: _efi_set_variable_mode: ops->set_variable() failed: Invalid argument.
/usr/sbin/grub-install: error: failed to register the EFI boot entry: Invalid argument.
Exit code: 1
---- End of grub-install recheck


efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0006,0002,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,6ad7128b-922e-4ee4-9baa-0ffaa5c0a297,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,GPT,78d781ef-526f-4d41-ad45-e941faf2f2be,0x276800,0x1f4000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootLrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0006* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,6ad7128b-922e-4ee4-9baa-0ffaa5c0a297,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
Warning: NVram was not modified.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[194340]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 72831: /bin/sh
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS CurrentSession entry (sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    557744128 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be 
    found at this location.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/LrsBootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS CurrentSession on sdb1
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on sda5

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-51-generic root=UUID=cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0006,0002,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,6ad7128b-922e-4ee4-9baa-0ffaa5c0a297,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,GPT,78d781ef-526f-4d41-ad45-e941faf2f2be,0x276800,0x1f4000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0006* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,6ad7128b-922e-4ee4-9baa-0ffaa5c0a297,0x1f4800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda2/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda2/Boot/bootx64.efi
2895d47544fd587b26c7e29be1295c27   sda2/Boot/fbx64.efi
114bd85eec32e3162958ea034020821d   sda2/Boot/grubx64.efi
dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sda2/Boot/mmx64.efi
114bd85eec32e3162958ea034020821d   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
bd03e0601b54eeb1adc9c9fd828c1b5c   sda2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
769147296d49018e33a91d936ab9de44   sda2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
ff6d345785671fbcea9561a3cbc47702   sda3/Boot/bootx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   sda3/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
bb971a4a02185961543c7903473a6680   sda3/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
5692b49c53b4401e76a43c82d7d496de   sda3/Microsoft/Boot/LrsBootmgr.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   sda8/ubuntu/shimx64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda5    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda6    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda7    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda8    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb1    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda7    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda8    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb1    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda6    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda7    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda8    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: F917B1FE-DF7E-4E6C-A0EB-2C49CF475D17
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048   2050047   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
sda2    2050048   2582527    532480   260M EFI System
sda3    2582528   4630527   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
sda4    4630528   4892671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
sda5    4892672 682748391 677855720 323.2G Microsoft basic data
sda6  682752000 896858111 214106112 102.1G Microsoft basic data
sda7  896860160 949291007  52430848    25G Microsoft basic data
sda8  949291008 976773119  27482112  13.1G Windows recovery environment
Disk sdb: 223.59 GiB, 240065183744 bytes, 468877312 sectors
Disk identifier: 23D32894-35FA-460A-940E-CA2E0827F347
      Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048 199999487 199997440 95.4G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD5000LPCX-2:;
1:1049kB:1050MB:1049MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
2:1050MB:1322MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
3:1322MB:2371MB:1049MB:fat32:Basic data partition:hidden;
4:2371MB:2505MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
5:2505MB:350GB:347GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:350GB:459GB:110GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
7:459GB:486GB:26.8GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
8:486GB:500GB:14.1GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
sdb:240GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA WDC WDS240G2G0A-:;
1:1049kB:102GB:102GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1 ntfs     E4028CBF028C9866                     40261cc0-6d21-48c9-9a78-fc1f9a470f63 WINRE_DRV   Basic data partition
├─sda2 vfat     8E8F-3521                            6ad7128b-922e-4ee4-9baa-0ffaa5c0a297 SYSTEM_DRV  EFI system partition
├─sda3 vfat     7C92-B9A8                            78d781ef-526f-4d41-ad45-e941faf2f2be LRS_ESP     Basic data partition
├─sda4                                               84fd7afe-e8e6-4afd-870c-7e8ae0f1321e             Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda5 ntfs     36D69613D695D409                     4b9c9681-fc99-425c-8d76-a4779b1ef9ac Windows8_OS Basic data partition
├─sda6 ntfs     CC52A8C952A8B99A                     f435d1fa-5965-4c38-bd9f-c7607d635829 New Volume  Basic data partition
├─sda7 ntfs     ECB29FF5B29FC28E                     35cd5b24-b5cf-43e5-9019-e16cff864908 Setup       Basic data partition
└─sda8 ntfs     4C969978969962EE                     f96a4ba4-9bf1-4613-b867-5475f0904a76 PBR_DRV     Basic data partition
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 ext4     cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418 5ef2933b-0372-40a0-b3a5-d3e0923db3b5             

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                   Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1              730.3M  27% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda3              497.7M  50% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda5              221.6G  31% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
sda6               64.5G  37% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
sda7               15.5G  38% /mnt/boot-sav/sda7
sda8                3.5G  73% /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
sdb1               13.3G  81% /

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda3              rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda5              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda6              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda7              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda8              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sdb1              rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418 root hd1,gpt1 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Windows Boot Manager (on sda2)   osprober-efi-8E8F-3521
Ubuntu   cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-51-generic   cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-48-generic   cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-62-generic   cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418
Windows Boot Manager (on sda2)   osprober-efi-8E8F-3521
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=cda62f48-fb99-4e55-8760-eeab23faf418 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=8E8F-3521  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sdb1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT="menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os  'osprober-efi-8E8F-3521' {"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  72.129295349 = 77.448241152   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  16.589977264 = 17.813352448   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  60.501693726 = 64.963198976   boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic                  1
  69.386852264 = 74.503565312   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic                  1
  16.589977264 = 17.813352448   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-51-generic                  2
  69.386852264 = 74.503565312   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  69.386852264 = 74.503565312   vmlinuz                                        1
  16.868160248 = 18.112049152   boot/initrd.img                                4
  69.928287506 = 75.084926976   boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic               2
  80.347923279 = 86.272925696   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic               2
  16.868160248 = 18.112049152   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-51-generic               4
  80.347923279 = 86.272925696   boot/initrd.img.old                            2
  80.347923279 = 86.272925696   initrd.img                                     2

===================== sdb1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17622 Sep  8 15:54 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Sep  8 15:54 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Sep  8 15:54 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Feb  8  2019 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Sep  8 15:54 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Feb  8  2019 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Feb  8  2019 41_custom


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown GPT Partiton Type
e7afbfbf4fa38a449a5b6213eb736c22

=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[194340]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 58516: /bin/bash
```

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229872/upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-grub-menu-hidden) after upgrading ubuntu hid the grub menu thats all.

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling grub on your efi partition.According to your description it's /dev/sda2

sudo grub-install /dev/sda2