# Grub menu does not show after updating Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

my laptop is dual-booted with windows and ubuntu, I've updated security updates on my Ubuntu OS today any after restarting Grub Menu/Boot menu does not show up. I have to blindly  press enter after hitting the arrow button certain times
The grub menu is there but it just won't show up

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142167/grub-menu-working-but-hidden-cant-make-it-visible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub menu working but hidden, can't make it visible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142167/grub-menu-working-but-hidden-cant-make-it-visible)